# Get image height in React grid

Tags: css, reactjs, grid

I am making masonry grid gallery in React and I have trouble getting image height after load and before resizing it with grid. I have `onLoad` handler on `img` but there I get only already resized image height where it should be original, to use it to calculate number of row spans. I am aware it could be pure css problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my `useEffect`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageRef.current && !loading) {
      const height = imageRef.current.clientHeight;
      console.log('height', height);
      const spansCount = Math.ceil(height / 10 + 1);
      setSpansCount(spansCount);
    }
  }, [imageRef.current, loading]);
```

And here is my `render`:

```js
 return (
    <div
      {...rest}
      className={styles.gallery__item}
      style={{ gridRowEnd: `span ${spansCount}` }}
    >
      <img
        src={image.previewURL}
        ref={imageRef}
        className={styles.gallery__img}
        alt={image.tags}
        onLoad={handleLoad}
      />
      <Placeholder
        ref={loaderRef}
        style={loading ? { display: 'block' } : { display: 'none' }}
      />
    </div>
```

Here is my non working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ardinghelli-6yye2?file=/src/components/ImageItem/ImageItem.js).

And here is **working** [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-einstein-txs6b?file=/src/components/ImageItem/ImageItem.js) with `react-load-image` package, but I am not sure why this is working and the first one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change this css on image:

```
.gallery__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; // not 100%
}
```